# Can not apply styles to custom components in React Native using styled-components?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, frontend, styled-components

I'm using `styled-components` in my React Native app to style it. Styling works fine on other components but when I try to style my custom created components then no style is applied.

In this case, no padding is applied.

Here is one of my code example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import styled from "styled-components/native";
import { BigTitle } from "./Titles";

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <MainTitle title="Hello World!" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;

const MainTitle = styled(BigTitle)`
  padding-top: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
`;
```

Here is the custom created component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import styled from "styled-components/native";

interface TitleProps {
  title: string;
}

export const BigTitle = (props: TitleProps) => {
  return <BigTitleText>{props.title}</BigTitleText>;
};

const BigTitleText = styled(Text)`
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1.8px;
  color: ${props => props.theme.textColor};
  font-family: ${props => props.theme.fontFamily};
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 1;
`;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use the **style** prop in the **BigTitle** component:

```
export const BigTitle = (props: TitleProps) => {
  return <BigTitleText style={props.style}>{props.title}</BigTitleText>;
};
```

Comment: I have also come up with this idea but it won't work.

Comment: I'm using styled-components in my projects and the solution that i gave you is working for me. Check out this example that i created in snack: https://snack.expo.io/@luaneduardo/styled-components-extend---example